# Multiple Angular-isotopes on one page

Tags: angularjs, jquery-isotope

Is there a way to initialise **two** [jquery-isotope](https://github.com/metafizzy/isotope) containers on same page using [angular-isotope](https://github.com/mankindsoftware/angular-isotope) ?
Only one works for me

http://plnkr.co/edit/RlARPYVf8ksLj6hYazrm?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['iso.directives']);

app.controller('isoCtrl', function($scope, ListService) {
    $scope.xList = ListService.xList;
    $scope.xList2 = ListService.xList2;

});

app.factory('ListService', function() {
    return {
        xList: [
          {name:'a', number:'1', date:'1360413309421', class:'purple'}
         ,{name:'b', number:'5', date:'1360213309421', class:'orange'}
         ,{name:'c', number:'10', date:'1360113309421', class:'blue'}
         ,{name:'d', number:'2', date:'1360113309421', class:'green'}
        ],
        xList2: [
          {name:'a2', number:'1', date:'1360413309421', class:'purple'}
         ,{name:'b2', number:'5', date:'1360213309421', class:'orange'}
         ,{name:'c2', number:'10', date:'1360113309421', class:'blue'}
         ,{name:'d2', number:'2', date:'1360113309421', class:'green'}
        ]

    };
});
```